# How to create a div on a page when clicking a button on another page

Tags: javascript

I need to write new text in a `p tag`  on the `'cart'`  page when I click on the `'submit'`  button on the `'index'` page. How can I do this with JavaScript. I have already tried with this

HTML page `index` :

```
<button onclick="myFunction()"> click me </button>
```

HTML page `cart` :

```
<p id="id"> </p>
```

`Js code` :

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('id').innerHtml = 'mytext';
}
```

but it does not work. How I can solve this? Thank you

Comment: Use textContent instead of innerHTML. Depends what u want to insert but in the example above use textContent

Comment: The javascript code you have on one page has no influence over your other html page. Like, none at all. You can't access another page content with javascript. You need to do it with a server side programming language

Comment: @gbalduzzi in fact it was just as I suspected. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index page and cart page in this reference, are different documents.

Accordingly, when you call your function on the index page, it can't find an element with the mentioned id in that document.

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('id').innerHtml = 'mytext';
}
```

The only way to perform this trick with only Javascript, is to use Cookies.
You can create a Cookie in the client's browser and save 'mytext' as an object, then retrieve it on another page.

See this page https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: There are multiple [client-side storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage) options other than cookies, also, prefer [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) over other reference sources when linking documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using a SPA structure with a framework like React or Vue this could be difficult - however its not impossible.

What you can do to circumvent the issue is that you can save a variable in `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` depending on whether or not you want it to remain between different browser sessions, then in your other page check if this variable exists and if it does make the required changes.

Then when it should change back you remove the variable from your localStorage again.

It's a bit of a hacky way, and the best way would be to either do this server side or to have a SPA and share the variable through global state.